# How to autofit the page content according to browser window size of different media using jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window-resize, jquery-ui-resizable

I have an HTML form with a text field and a submit button.

The text field contains a URL, and clicking the submit button, the user is redirected to that URL.

I want to display the new window according to the browser window size of the media on which user is watching the webpage.

Can I achieve this using jQuery/JavaScript?

I tried using `resizeTo()`, but as it only accepts hardcoded values of width and height it will not be able to determine the browser window size of the medium on which user is viewing the webpage.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you are not the one who coded the css of the page you are linking to. Otherwise i would simply advise you to change the css of that page to a responsive css you could use something like [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

I think javascript as jQuery is limited to the window or document it is implemented in. So i don’t think that it’s possible to change an other windows content size with it.

But there is a way to get the size of the current window, which is most likely to be the size of the window you redirect to and that would be accomplished like this:

```
function changeSize() {
    var windowSize = parseInt(document.body.clientWidth);
    if (windowSize < 660) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Unfortunately i think you knew that already …